# Visual Studio Code for Mac. Terminal output is wrapped onto next line

Tags: terminal, width

Using Visual Studio Code on my Mac. Version 1.80.0

I am running some simple python code, the output seems to be wrapped in the integrated terminal output, see picture

I was expecting all the output to be non wrapped.  There is a huge amount of empty space on the right hand side of my terminal screen that is not being utilised.

I have tried right clicking and selecting "Toggle Size to Content Width" on the pop up context menu, but this has not helped.    This is not about the code editor section, just the integrated terminal window.

Please could someone explain how to resolve this in clear English.  I am not expert.